# How to declare events barButtonItem1_ItemClick for DXMenuItem of DevExpress?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I get an error when declaring `DXMenuItem`, here is my code:

```
private void barButtonItem1_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}

private void gridview1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
      ...
      // fault warning at the bottom line
      // No overload for 'barButtonItem1_ItemClick' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'
      DXMenuItem menuItemAdd = new DXMenuItem("Add", new EventHandler(barButtonItem1_ItemClick), 3);
      ...
}
```

Comment: Your posted makes very little sense. Not sure what you are doing trying to create a instance of control.

Answer (score 0):

Check which delegate type the constructor actually takes, and pass that instead.

Or just remove `new EventHandler` entirely; C# will implicitly create the delegate for you.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `EventHandler` delegate is:

```
delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

But your `barButtonItem1_ItemClick` method have another signature. It uses `ItemClickEventArgs` type for `e` parameter instead of `EventArgs`. You must use method with the same signature as `EventHandler` delegate. Something like this:

```
private void DXMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Also you can omit the `EventHandler` constructor and use your method directly (syntactic sugar):

```
DXMenuItem menuItemAdd = new DXMenuItem("Add", DXMenuItem_Click, 3);
```